# Cannot install Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit server on Intel Xeon Scalable processors with VMware

Tags: server, 17.10, 64-bit, vmware, intel

I've been unable to get Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit server installed on a new set of servers with Intel Xeon Scalable processors running VMware ESXi 6.5 U1. Once I load up the Ubuntu installer, it displays a gray screen and gets stuck there.

I've been able to install this OS image on older servers with Intel v4 processors with no issues. I've also been able to install Ubuntu 17.10 32-bit server, Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit desktop, and Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit server on the new servers with Intel Xeon Scalable processors. I've also been able to install the Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit server directly onto the baremetal server with Intel Xeon Scalable Processors and no ESXi hypervisor intsalled.

The issue seems to be specifically with the interop of Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit server in a VMware environment running on Intel Xeon Scalable processors.

Has anybody seen this issue or have any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I have this Problem also. I usee the maschine kompatibiliti Mode VM-Version 10.

after this it was OK for me.